# Best Git strategy to commit multiple stories that requires the commits to be merged consecutively

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm occasionally facing a situation where I work on stories that depend on the previous story that has not been merged yet.

For example. I worked on a commit on branch A that contains a reusable component.
It is not merged yet because of the company's sprint structure.
Then I work on a commit on branch B that requires the branch A's commit that contains a reusable component.
And we want to merge both A and B branch at the same time to our master as we have strict delivery time.

May be I wasnt using right terms, but I could not find a correct way to phrase this in my search.

What's the best Git strategy for such scenario? Should I rebase commit B to commit A and continue to work? Will this create conflict when we attempt to push both A and B at the same time in Github?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best Git strategy for such scenario? Should I rebase commit B to commit A and continue to work? Will this create conflict when we attempt to push both A and B at the same time in Github?

Not at all, this is standard git workflow.

Provided `B` has been branched off `A`, when you'll make your pull request `B > master` everything in `A` will indeed be included.

Before the merge :

```
---C1---C2---C3 <<< master
         \
          C4---C5 <<< A
                 \
                  C6---C7 <<< B
```

and afterwards :

```
---C1---C2---C3---------------C8 <<< master
         \                   /
          C4---C5 <<< A     /
                 \         /
                  C6------C7 <<< B
```

At this point, every commit here is reachable from `C8` (the merge commit on `master`)